# Call upon several values from a database

Tags: php, javascript, database

I am trying to retrieve like several different values from a table. I got it working, but it is actually only sending me the last value it calls. I have done several different things trying to call all my values, but it is not working. Here is what I have.

```
$infoChanger = $_GET['changer'];
$username = $_GET['user'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM Login_Info WHERE user='".$username."'";
$r = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($r);

if ($row[7] != "") 
{
    if ( $infoChanger == 1 ) {
        echo $row['user'];
    }
    else if ( $infoChanger == 2 ) {
        echo $row['health'];
    }
    else if ( $infoChanger == 3 ) {
        echo $row['maxHealth'];
    }
    else if ( $infoChanger == 4 ) {
        echo $row['gold'];
    }
    else if ( $infoChanger == 5 ) {
        echo $row['xp'];
    }
    else if ( $infoChanger == 6 ) {
        echo $row['xpRequire'];
    }
    else if ( $infoChanger == 7 ) {
        echo $row['eg'];
    }
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```

This was my last attempt to try to do it. But it only return the value of the last one "eg". I have it set on an a loop to call here is what I use to call it.

```
function recallCharInfo(user)
{
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
      alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
      return
    }
    while (infoChanger < 7) {
      infoChanger += 1;
      xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
      var url="charinfo.php?user=" + user + "&changer=" + infoChanger;
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged
      xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get them all to display, but just isn't working the way and I don't want to make a function for each one value I am trying to call. Does anyone know what is wrong with this or have I just done this wrong?

Comment: what do you get if you run print_r($row) after the fetch array?

Comment: also, why not return the whole array JSON encoded and parse the value you want in Javascript?

Comment: I get the same thing as I use echo. The problem still exist.

Comment: if you run print_r($row) right after mysql_fetch_array and only see one value, then your database is only returning the one value.

Comment: The way I have it right now it should be only returning one value at a time. I had another way before this where it should return all the values, but it didn't work and still return only the very last value. So I switch to this if I set the call in a loop and have the value I am calling set to a number and then it will send that number and it will get the value I am calling for and return it to put it in the spot it is suppose to be which is done in the stateChanged function.

Comment: Oh... When I typed in print_r I forgot to take out the cell I was calling from... My bad. Okay, it did print the whole row now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific case, array indexes start at 0, so if those are all the rows in your array $row[7] will never be anything, and will always return false.

Your initial check should be:

```
if($row !== false && $row[6] != "")
```

For an alternate solution to looping:

You're php can be:

```
$infoChanger = $_GET['changer'];
$username = $_GET['user'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM Login_Info WHERE user='".$username."'";
$r = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($r);
echo json_encode($row);
```

That should return the whole row as a JSON object which you can then parse into a Javascript object in your success method with:

```
var rowData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then you should be able to access all your fields with

```
rowData.user;
and
rowData.health;
```